# MGF/ expectation Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am stuck with something that seems easy but i cannot recall how to figure it out?
Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two standard gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Then how to calculate $\mathbb{E}\bigg(\exp(\lambda_1.G_1)\exp(\lambda_2.G_2)\bigg)$

where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are constants with $\mathbb{E}\big[G_1.G_2\big]=\rho$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem 1:

Let $(X,Y)$ be jointly gaussian, $Cov(X,Y) =0$ iff $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Theorem 2:

when $(G_1,G_2)$ are jointly Gaussian, it is possible to write

$G_2 = a G_1 + (G_2-aG_1)$ for some value of $a$ such that, where a can be found using 1.

Let's see

$Cov(aG_1, G_2-aG_1) = a Cov(G_1,G_2) - a^2 Var(G_1) = a\rho - a^2$, so we need to make $a=\rho$ (unsurprisingly)

---

so $G_2=\rho G_1 + (G_2-\rho G_1)$ where $\rho G_1$  and $(G_2-\rho G_1)$ are independent

Note $G_2 - \rho G_1$ is Guassian with mean $0$, and $Var(G_2-\rho G_1)= 1-\rho^2$

Then your mgf is

$E(\exp(\lambda_1 G_1 + \lambda_2 \rho G_1 + \lambda_2(G_2-\rho G_1))) = E\exp((\lambda_1+\lambda_2\rho)G_1)E\exp(\lambda_2(G_2-\rho G_1))$

where i used WHAT in the last line? can you take it from there using the mgf of 1-d Gaussian?

EDIT: the alternative is computing the integral directly. if you choose to do that, good luck :P

Comment: The variance of G_2-rho.G_1 is 1-rho^2, not (1-rho)^2. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1)$ and $\Bbb{E}(XY)=\rho\neq0$ then the joint pdf is
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(x^2−2ρxy+y^2)\right]
$$
so that the bivariate Moment generating function is
$$\small
\begin{align}
M(t_1,t_2)&=\Bbb{E}\left(e^{tX+t_2Y}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tx+t_2y}\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(x^2−2ρxy+y^2)\right]{\rm d}x{\rm d}y\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-\tfrac{(x-\alpha)^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}-\frac{1}{2}(y-\beta)^2+\frac{1}{2}(t_1^2+2\rho t_1t_2+t_2^2)\right]{\rm d}x{\rm d}y\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\underbrace{\left\{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-\tfrac{(x-\alpha)^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right]{\rm d}x\right\}}_{=\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(y-\beta)^2\right]{\rm d}y\cdot\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\left(t_1^2+2\rho t_1 t_2+t_2^2\right)\right\}\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}(y-\beta)^2\right]{\rm d}y}_{=1}\cdot\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\left(t_1^2+2\rho t_1 t_2+t_2^2\right)\right\}\\
&=\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\left(t_1^2+2\rho t_1 t_2+t_2^2\right)\right\}
\end{align}
$$
where we called $\alpha=\left[x-(\rho y+(1-\rho^2)t_1)\right]^2$ and $\beta=\left[y-(\rho t_1+t_2)\right]^2$.